# Why does Server 14.04.1 install the boot loader to my USB drive instead of the hard disk?

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation

Ok, I don't *know* that's what it's doing. What I *know* is that, after I finish installing the OS, I pull out the thumb drive to reboot, and at that point the computer just sits there. I figure, "Hey, that install must be broke," so I put the thumb drive back in there to try again--and lo, it works!

What gives? How do I make it STOP THAT?!

P.S. Because you almost *have* to ask, I'm using guided LVM with encryption, and I'm picking the 750 gig hard disk to partition (not the one gig usb), because I don't think I'm qualified to decide how to partition my disks and decide what gets installed where.

...Then again, it's starting to feel like I'm more qualified than the installer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I actually did: jerk out the install media before the installer noticed it. Kind of the worst/best solution ever, if you ask me.

The other suggestions here will probably work if you understand enough about installing Linux to understand... Well, you know. What they were talking about. That said, I really had neither the know-how nor the patience to go about babying Ubuntu into actually working, so "pull out USB stick before boot loader option screen" has a certain charm, as answers go.

Answer (score 1):

If you try picking "something else" on the page that asks you where and how you want to install it, you can select where you want the bootloader. You will have to set up which disk to use for the / mount point and elect to use encryption manually but it will let you choose where to install the bootloader and should at least get you a fully bootable, fully functional, system.

Comment: There isn't an option at some point during the guided installation process where I can override the target for the boot loader? :(

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this problem on my machine:

Recreate your install USB.

Boot to USB and select Fix A Broken System.

Go through the prompts.

Select Re-install GRUB Bootloader and enter /dev/sda for location.

Select Reboot system.

Hope this helps!